# sfdx force:org:create throwing an error after creating a Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, salesforcedx-cli, force-org-create

I'm running sfdx force:org:create command to create a Developer Sandbox. The sandbox creation is done successfully but it's throwing an error during the activation. The error message reads as **"ERROR running force:org:create:  Error authenticating with auth code due to: Value is undefined"**. Not sure what it really means in this context.

Requesting for any help on this.

Here's the command that I executed:

*sfdx force:org:create autoActivate=true description="Test PK Create DX" licenseType=Developer sandboxName=clone4 --targetusername prodOrg --type sandbox --nonamespace --setalias clone4 --wait 30 --setdefaultusername*

Also, please find the screenshot attached.

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Could you please run sfdx force:config:list and see if prodOrg is listed and if it is could you please run sfdx force:org:list and see if the connection status is connected

Comment: Hey @AbhijithE , yeah I tried that.. prodOrg is listed and its status is Connected. I also made the prodOrg as the default org as well and tried the command and it still failed. :(